# Android Youtube video upload

Tags: android, api, http, post, youtube

I followed this [link](http://nilvec.com/implementing-client-side-oauth-on-android) and I successfully created an oauth access to youtube, in my Android APP.

Then I am asking, how do I upload a video on my account?

After accessing my account I have the token, but I saw that I have to do an http request to upload the video. I saw many sites but I still cannot resolve this problem...

How to do it?

Comment: YouTube direct upload sounds what you might want to try; https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Direct_uploading

Comment: And how can i do it in Java?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/googleapis-youtube-api-uploads.pdf) is probably what you are looking for, particularly slide 30. It comes with nice code examples. But it will only upload into their own account.

Comment: This was probably true, but intent_SEND sends the video to the youtube app, not to the web.
I need a way to authenticate and then update video on an account chosen by me without letting the user choose the account